# Un-canceling a Stripe subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

Suppose a user wants to cancel their subscription, so I issue a command like this:

```
stripe_subscription.delete(at_period_end: true)
```

Later, though—before the period ends—the user changes their mind. Is there a call I can issue to undo the scheduled cancellation?

If not, what's the best way to implement this? My best guess looks like this:

```
new_subscription = stripe_customer.subscriptions.create(plan: stripe_subscription.plan.id, trial_end: stripe_subscription.current_period_end)
stripe_subscription.delete()   # if permitted
self.stripe_subscription = new_subscription
save!
```

Is there something better I can do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the subscription is still active, you just have to [update](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription) the current subscription and pass the plan id once again and it would resume the subscription.

In PHP you would do:

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve("cus_XXX");
$subscription = $customer->subscriptions->retrieve("sub_YYY");
$subscription->plan = "myPlanId";
$subscription->save();
```

This is covered in one of Stripe's support article in more details [here](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/canceling-pausing#reactivating-canceled-subscriptions).

Comment: The linked support article calls out that this can also be done via the Stripe Dashboard in case it's a one-off and not worth implementing via the API.

Comment: Updated permalink to Stripe's subsection on reactivating canceled subs: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/canceling-pausing#reactivating-canceled-subscriptions

Comment: It appears (based on both my testing and the docs) that if a subscription has reached the end of its cancellation date (meaning it either got canceled immediately or its cancellation date has passed) then you _cannot_ reactivate it, you must create a brand new.

Comment: That link was very helpful. Thanks. For what it's worth, if you want to do this, you probably don't want to run the `delete` method on a Stripe subscription to cancel it, but instead do an update on the Stripe subscription and set the `cancel_at_period_end` argument to `true`.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if the accepted answer is an old one, but for the latest version of Stripe you have to do this (in PHP):

```
$sub->cancel_at_period_end = false;
return $sub->save();
```

Comment: To my mind that would suggest that the subscription would be cancelled immediately rather than at the end of the period. Is this accurate? Could you be more specific about the 'latest version' you refer to?

Comment: In my testing I have seen that the subscription is active until the renewal date is reached. When that happens, the API checks if this flag called "cancel_at_period_end" is set to true or false. If true, it does not renew and cancels it instead. OTOH if set to false it renews. So IMO this is just a flag and for the API to decide whether to cancel or renew and it only affects at the time of actual renewal.

Comment: I should never have doubted you, the same is true for the C# solution which I'll add separately but you get my vote!

Comment: Indeed. C# was the same (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/canceling-pausing).    subscriptionService.Update(
          subscriptionId: ss.Id,
           new SubscriptionUpdateOptions {
             CancelAtPeriodEnd = false,
           }
        );

Answer (score 3):

From the dashboard. Go to your Subscription details and click `Edit Details` top corner right. A modal untitled "Reactivate subscription" should pop saying

> This subscription is set to cancel at the end of the period. You can
>   reactivate the subscription and it'll continue as usual.

Click `Reactivate`

**EDIT**

It seems that the actions now appear on mouse over the remaining days before cancellation:

[image]

Note that it wont show if the subscription is already canceled.

Comment: Can't seem to find this. Screenshots would help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually exist

Comment: I have added a screenshot. Note that it wont show if the subscription is already canceled.

Answer (score 1):

As per the above answer from Supersan, this solution also works for C# using the latest Stripe.net library 21.4.1

```
 var items = new [] { new SubscriptionItemUpdateOption() { Id = i.Id, PlanId = i.Plan.Id } }.ToList();
 var updateOptions = new SubscriptionUpdateOptions { Items = updatedItems, CancelAtPeriodEnd = false };
 await subscriptionService.UpdateAsync(externalSubscriptionId, updateOptions);
```

Where I've just set the Id and Plan Id to whatever they were before. Not sure if these are necessary if you aren't using multiple plan subscriptions.